# How to catch carriage return / line feed in case statement

Tags: shell-script, special-characters

I tried the following to no avail and couldn't find any documentation.

```
read Option
case $Option in
    [1] ) echo "1" ;;
    [2] ) echo "2" ;;
    [$'\n'] ) echo "LF" ;;
    [0] ) exit ;;
    * ) echo "Invalid input" ;;
esac
```

The following works though.

```
$ x="                                         
> "
$ if [ "$x" = $'\n' ]; then echo "newline"; fi
newline
```

Comment: You don't need `[...]` to enclose a single character in any of those cases.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since `read` only reads a single line of input, sans newline, you just want to check for the empty string:

```
read Option
case $Option in
    1 ) echo "1" ;;
    2 ) echo "2" ;;
    "" ) echo "LF" ;;
    0 ) exit ;;
    * ) echo "Invalid input" ;;
esac
```

`[1]` and `1` (and similarly for the other one-character classes) match the same strings as patterns.

Comment: Technically, without `-r`, `read` can read more than one line of input (if the user enters a backslash at the end of all but the last line) , but in any case even in that case, `$Option` won't contain a newline character (that backslash+newline is interpreted as a line continuation by `read`).

Comment: Note that with the default value of `$IFS`, if the user enters any combination of TAB and space characters, that code will output `LF`. Generally, you need `IFS= read -r Option` to read a line `r`aw from the user. If the user ends input with Ctrl+D, you'll also get LF. If the user enters NUL characters, the behaviour will vary with the shell implementation.

Comment: Right; either I didn't know that in 2015, or I underestimated the importance of using them.

Answer (score 3):

`read` will strip it. The case statement itself works.

```
#read Option
Option='
'
case "$Option" in
    [1] ) echo "1" ;;
    [2] ) echo "2" ;;
    [$'\n'] ) echo "LF" ;;
    [0] ) exit ;;
    * ) echo "Invalid input" ;;
esac
#Outputs: LF
```

Answer (score 0):

Though I remain unable to find, how to catch the actual newline with `case` directly, the following invoking an external program (like `sed`).

In my example below, all blanks and non-printable characters are invalid -- as is the blank-space -- so I substitute them all with a literal " ":

```bash
case "${Option//[^[:print:]]/ }" in
*\ *)
    # Handle error
    ;;
...
esac
```